# Load spark dataframe rows into memory only if their IDs are in a whitelist

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark process that processes about a million signals per job and joins those rows with a giant table (5 billion rows). The entire table in memory is about 500GB, so I was wondering if it would be possible to only load the relevant rows into memory, i.e.

```
val fileIds = incomingSignals("fileIds").dropDuplicates()
val df = spark.read.parquet(fileLocation).where(fileIds.contains(col("fileId")))
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this feasible with potentially a million rows in the filter clause (fileIds.count > 1000000)
2. Can you filter the read *before* actually loading irrelevant rows into memory? (I assume the .where function loads into memory first and then filters)
3. Does this even work with parquet files? I assume those have to be loaded into memory before any kind of processing/filtering can be done on them.

Comment: Streaming or Structured Streaming? Should mention that in the body of the question, not just the tag.

Comment: Is contains correct? Isin I would have thought.

Answer (score 2):

1. Filtering with more than a million rows in the filter clause should be feasible, but not optimal. From my understanding, the giant table here seems to be reused across multiple streaming inputs. The optimal way would be to persist that table in memory & partitioning it by the "fileId" column. This would lead to shuffling of only the incoming signal dataframe while joining (which is much smaller than the other table).
2. For your where clause, spark will read each record in memory, apply the filter & then decide to either drop it or not. Which means individual records will be loaded into memory while reading the file, but all records will never be in memory (unless your filter removes nothing). You can use the `explain` command to see the detailed physical plan created by your query.
3. In case of a contains filter matching the exact column content as is the case here, parquet should be able to filter on the serialized record content itself in memory. In case you were doing a string equalsIgnoreCase or any other such operation, it would have needed to load the record in memory, deserialize to string & then perform the operation.